# How to update the license of Visual studio automatically?

Tags: visual-studio

When we manually open the visiual studio and from help menu and click on register, then the license is getting updated.But, we are using visual studio for automation with CI tools like jenkins.Where, we will use the devenv command line tool.Here, we don' launch the shortcut.This command line version is not updating the license automatically. So, every 10 days our compilation is failing and we need to manually open visual studio and refresh the license.

We are getting this error with compilation.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.0.28307.145.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

The license for Visual Studio has expired.

Your license for this product is expired and could not be refreshed. Please connect to the internet to continue to use this product.
```

Visual studio 2017
[Visual studio workloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxb3G.png)

But when I see the features/workloads of build tools, many are missing.
[Build tools work loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB44P.png)

Comment: Why do you use a Visual Studio that requires a license in your CI instead of the VS Build Tools?

Comment: Build tools is not having all the features which need to be installed for c++ desktop applications

Comment: You're likely missing a workload, have you identified which of your needs is missing from the build tools?

Comment: I have added both the snaps now, can you check once and suggest

Comment: Also I tried build tools with these installations only but there is no devenv.com/exe there